# Ruby and integers

Tags: ruby

I have a question to get a better understanding of how Ruby operates with integers.

I have a block of code:

```
class Machine


 @@users = {}

  def initialize(username, password)
    puts "username: #{username}"
    puts "password: #{password}"
    @username = username
    @password = password
    @@users[username] = password
    @files = {}
  end

  def create(filename)
    time = Time.now
    @files[filename] = time
    puts "#{filename} was created by #{@username} at #{time}."
  end

  def Machine.get_users
    @@users
  end
end

my_machine = Machine.new("eric", 01234)
```

The puts output for that is as follows:

```
username: eric
password: 668
```

Why does Ruby change the value of the password if it has a leading zero?

Comment: Because, as in many other languages as well, a leading 0 indicates that this is an _octal_ number.

Comment: (The _real_ question here would be, how would one _ever_ come up with the idea to handle passwords as integers? One wouldn’t, of course. Even if it was some kind of weird system that only allows digits in a password, one would still store and handle it as a string value only. The fact that something consists of digits only, does not necessarily make it a _number_.)

Comment: I was just typing a quick example to test my code :-) and i came across this output and it peaked my curiosity.   Thanks for the response, it makes sense to me now.

Comment: By the way, `01234` is bad style. If you want to use a true octal (say, while setting File permissions in Linux) use the format `0o123`. This is in line with the common hex notation `0x1FE` or binary `0b110`